# How to configure MediaWiki to allow uploading text/plain ".conf' files

Tags: mediawiki, uploading, configuration, content-type

I'm having a heck of a time getting our internal MediaWiki to allow CONF file uploads. A CONF file is just a plain text file with a `*.conf` extension.

In `...\LocalSettings.php`, I added `txt` and `conf` to the array of [`$wgFileExtensions`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgFileExtensions). The extensions are recognized after an apache restart (see the preferred file types in the image below). [`$wgCheckFileExtensions`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCheckFileExtensions) is false and [`$wgStrictFileExtensions`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgStrictFileExtensions) is false.

Yet when I try to upload, I get a the following warning:

> File extension ".conf" does not match the detected MIME type of the file (text/plain)

Not that this is ***not*** an error and the file is ***not*** uploaded. (I also have "Ignore warnings" checked). An image of a failed attempt is shown below.

[image: "Upload warning" on the "Upload file" page]

How does one enable and upload a CONF file to MediaWiki?

Answer (score 3):

As Stephen Ostermiller says, in this case you want to add "conf" to the line beginning with "text/plain" in:

```
includes/mime.types
```

In other cases though it may not be this simple.  When you upload a file, mediawiki executes the PHP function

```
mime_content_type("my_uploaded.wth");
```

which takes the result and looks it up in includes/mime.types.  If you find that php doesn't recognize a file type you want to accept, you can set [$wgMimeDetectorCommand](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgMimeDetectorCommand) in LocalSettings.php to designate a custom command to analyze files for you.  Here's an example that uses a magic.mgc file with more file type information than the default:

```
$wgMimeDetectorCommand = "/usr/bin/file -bi -m /usr/local/share/magic.mgc";
```

But you could specify a path to any executable and customize to your heart's content.  So you could set

```
$wgMimeDetectorCommand = "/usr/local/sbin/my_custom_mimechecker.py
```

Which tries the file command above, say, and adds some custom logic.  In the end, if the following command is run:

```
/usr/local/sbin/my_custom_mimechecker.py my_uploaded.wth
```

and it returns (prints to STDOUT and exits with status 0)

```
application/heck; charset=binary
```

and you have a line in mime.types

```
application/heck wtg wth wti wtj
```

I.e. the wth extension of the uploaded file matches the output of the $wgMimeDetectorCommand, the upload will be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the MediaWiki documentation for mime type detection](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:MIME_type_detection#MIME_type_validation).   It says that you need to add modify two files:

#### mime.types

Add `conf` to the `text/plain` line

#### mime.info

Ensure that `text/plain` is on the line ending in `[TEXT]`